# JPA how to make composite Foreign Keys from two different table part of composite Primary Key of a single table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, composite-key

Following is the structure of my table:

```
Table Campaign{
Camp_id(PK),
other columns...
}

Table User{
user_id(PK),
other columns...
}

Table Candidate{
cand_id(PK),
other columns...
}

Table Result{
user_id(PK),
camp_id(PK),
cand_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

entity TableCampaign

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAMPAIGN")
public class Campaign implements Serializable {
    
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @Id
    @Column(name="CAMP_ID")
    Long campId
    ....
}
```

entity User

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    Long userId
    ....
}
```

entity Candidate

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CANDIDATE")
public class Candidate implements Serializable {
    
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @Id
    @Column(name="CAND_ID")
    Long candId
    ....
}
```

entity Result

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RESULT")
public class Result implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ResultId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAND_ID")
    private Candidate candidate;
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ResultId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAMP_ID")
    private Campaign campaign;

}
```